# Sqlite3 putting input field values into insert statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron

I have sqlite database with 4 columns

```
Name
Age
bloodGroup
lastdate
```

and 4 input fields and saving button as following:

```
<input type="text" name="" id="patientName">
<input type="number" name="" id="PatientAge">
<input type="text" name="" id="PatientBloodGroup">
<input type="date" name="" id="PatientLastDate">
<button id="savebtn"> Save </button>
```

and i used the following javascript code to take the input values and insert them into the columns of the database :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('savebtn').addEventListener('click', saveFunction);
    function saveFunction(){
        const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
        let db = new sqlite3.Database('./database_name');
        var patientName = document.getElementById('patientName').value;
        var patientAge = document.getElementById('patientAge').value;
        var patinetBloodGroup =   document.getElementById('patientBloodGroup').value;
        var PatientLastDate = document.getElementById('patientLastDate').value;

        db.run(`INSERT INTO info(Name, Age, bloodGroup, lastdate) VALUES(patientName, patientAge, patientBloodGroup, PatientLastDate), function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err.message);
            }
            console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
        });
        db.close();
    } 
</script>
```

When the program is run it gives this error message :

> SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: patientName.

Comment: what is your db schema? it says the table `info` doesn't have the column `Name` in it

Comment: I'm sorry i have written the error message by mistake. The actual error message as the following : 

    SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: patientName. @AritraChakraborty

Comment: The problem is that you are running a literal SQL string without substituting the variable values in.  Most databases will interpret this as an instruction to get the value from the field named `patientName` which clearly isn't what you want.  Try something like the 'Insert Multiple Records' part on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp (obviously, you only want one record.

Comment: when i try the example in w3school the error changes to : SQLITE_ERROR: 1 values for 4 columns @GregHNZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will seem silly but you're not enclosing the values with a quote and also not evaluating the variables. 
The `INSERT INTO` query will be in the form of

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Stavanger', 'Norway');
```

So change your db query to:

```
db.run(`INSERT INTO info(Name, Age, bloodGroup, lastdate) VALUES('${patientName}', '${patientAge}', '${patientBloodGroup}', '${PatientLastDate}')`), function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err.message);
    }
    console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
});
```

Now, this code is obviously susceptible to SQL injection. You should use prepared statement

```
db.run(`INSERT INTO info(Name, Age, bloodGroup, lastdate) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`, patientName, patientAge, patientBloodGroup, PatientLastDate), function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err.message);
    }
    console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
});
```